# In Angular 8, How to get form all values into JSON on click submit button?

Tags: angular-reactive-forms, angular8

I want to push form data with keys and values into JSON format from click on the submit button.

I don't want to create JSON manually. Please help me to short out this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use reactive forms from Angular.

Follow the steps below.

1. Create a Form Group and define the variables you need.

   ```
     export class ProfileEditorComponent {
         profileForm = new FormGroup({
         firstName: new FormControl(''),
         lastName: new FormControl(''),
     });


    onSubmit() {        
      console.warn(this.profileForm.value);
     }
   }
   ```
2. Create your html file like below.

   ```
     <form [formGroup]="profileForm">

    <label>
     First Name:
     <input type="text" formControlName="firstName">
   </label>

   <label>
    Last Name:
   <input type="text" formControlName="lastName">
   </label>

   <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
   ```

Please find the guide for the same. 
https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms